# prefetch_related with nested m2m

Tags: django, django-models

Given the following models I would like to improve the performance of the filter to avoid unnecessary calls to DB.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    b = ManyToManyField(B)

class B(models.Model):
    c = ManyToManyField(C)

class C(models.Model):
    d = ManyToManyField(D)

class D(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField()
```

How could I achieve this with *prefetch_related*?

`''.join(A.objects.filter(b__c__d=self.d).prefetch_related('`**??**'`).values_list('name', flat=True))`

Comment: That without `prefetch_related` should use just one query. That is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

It works in a similar fashion to your filter (`b__c__d`). Just prefetch:

```
''.join(A.objects.filter(b__c__d=self.d).prefetch_related('b__c__d').values_list('name', flat=True))
```